# How to find the number of days between two dates in format %Y%m%d if one of the day is the list element?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y%m%d")
```

I have today date. Now I want to see the difference between a date as a list element in the same format and today's date. How can I?

Edit : This is my code -

```
today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime ("%Y%m%d")

for i,val in enumerate(date):
    d = date[i] = datetime.datetime.strptime (val,"%d-%b-%Y").strftime ("%Y%m%d")
    # our dates are now converted into 20160101 format
    delta = date(today) - date(d)
    if delta.days < 3:
        print "true"
    else:
        print "false"
```

Comment: Why did you use `strftime` on the `datetime.datetime` object if you wanted to do date calculations? Are you familiar with what `strftime` does?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 No I'm new to python. Sir, may you provide me the code?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The dates in the date list were in %d-%b-%Y format already

Comment: "No I'm new to python" - If you're writing code and you don't know what it does, the first step is to Google it. Documentation would be a good start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are converting back to a string when you have the date objects already:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.now()
dates = ['10-Jan-2016', '24-Oct-2016']

for val in dates:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(val, '%d-%b-%Y')
    delta = today - date
    if delta.days < 3:
        print("true")
    else:
        print("false")
```

Output:

```
false
true
```